# Is there any philosophical tenet to “Things happen when you least expect it”?

Tags: metaphysics, theory

Throughout my life, whenever I anticipated something that was going to happen; it turned out that it doesn’t. Yet things I never could have expected seemed to always come out of left field and hit me like a ton of bricks. I am always worried something will happen to my sister on the subway. I am dreading running into my high school crush. I am always on guard for these things and they never happen. If I let my guard down; could they happen and if I want to be safe; should I just keep worrying about it?

This is what I have deemed to be speculative philosophy but I wonder if any of the great thinkers have something similar.

Comment: This most closely resembles selective perception or selective memory. It's a logical fallacy humans are prone to fall prey to, where you more easily remember an event that happened unexpectedly (or disappointed isolated hopes) than all the events that happened exactly as expected.